# How to access particular elements in a multi-map C++

Tags: c++, multimap

I have implemented a multi-map, but I​ was wondering how do I access the first 5 elements of a multimap?

I tried using a for-loop, but that didn't work out. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you talking about a `std::multimap`? If not, we don't know the interface of your own implementation, without code.

Comment: Please post the code you tried (in the form of a [MCVE]).

Comment: You probably didn't implement a multimap but you may using one. Where's the code?

Comment: How can you think that posting a screenshot of your code could be any better than pasting the code directly?

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image. See the markdown formatting help page if you need help formatting it as a code block. Also, please make a [mre].

Comment: The included code sample is much better than the image link you had before. Best of all would be to make it a short, complete source file that we can compile without any additional modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it would be easier to help you if you were to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as text, formatted as a code sample, I think I still understand what you’re asking.

This looks like a learning exercise that you want to solve on your own.  But I can give some advice.

What you want to do is check two conditions: that you’ve read five elements, or that you’ve run out of them.  Declare both a loop counter initialized to 0 and an iterator.initialized to `.begin()`.  Loop until the counter is equal to 5 **or** the iterator is equal to `.end()`.  On each iteration, increment both the counter and the iterator.  You might express this as a `while` loop, but you could also do it with comma operators in your `for` loop.

Also, please indent your code properly and use braces under your `for` and `if` statements.  It’ll save you from writing a lot of bugs and make your code much easier to read.